# Concurrent Erlang Code

Tags: concurrency, erlang

From an old exam, there is a question I don't understand the answer to. The module for the question looks like this:

```
-module(p4).
-export([start/0, init/0, f1/1, f2/1, f3/2]).

start() ->
    spawn(fun() -> init() end).

init() ->  loop(0).

loop(N) ->
    receive
        {f1, Pid} ->
            Pid ! {f1r, self(), N},
            loop(N);
        {f2, Pid} ->
            Pid ! {f2r, self()},
            loop(N+1);
        {f3, Pid, M} ->
            Pid ! {f3r, self()},
            loop(M)
    end.

f1(Serv) ->
    Serv ! {f1, self()},
    receive {f1r, Serv, N} -> N end.

f2(Serv) ->
    Serv ! {f2, self()},
    receive {f2r, Serv} -> ok end.

f3(Serv, N) ->
    Serv ! {f3, self(), N},
    receive {f3r, Serv} -> ok end.
```

The question asks to consider the following function as part of the code, and what the result of the function would be. The correct answer is 2. I would think it'd be 3, since the "increase-call" `f2(Server)` is after the response of `self()!{f1r, Server, 2}`.

```
    test3() ->
      Server = start(),
      self()!{f1r, Server, 2},
      f2(Server),
      f1(Server).
```

My questions are:

- Why is the answer 2 and not 3, AND how does the `self()!{f1r, Server, 2}` work?
- Isn't the `self()!{f1r, Server, 2}` a response from the receive clause in the `loop(N)` of the `f1(Serv)` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self()!{f1r, Server, 2}` sends the `{f1r, Server, 2}` to itself.
This message will wait in the inbox until received.

Then `f2` gets executed and then `f1`.

It is in this last function, when the last line `receive {f1r, Serv, N} -> N end` is executed, the process running `test3` receives the message waiting in the inbox (the one sent to itself) and returns the 2 in that message.

Note that at the end of the program, there would have been a `{f1r, <process number>, N}` waiting in the inbox, N having a value of 1.

Comment: Is it then correct that the receive-clause in the loop function receives the `Serv ! {f1, self()}` from the final `f1(Server)` call, but instead of sending back `{f1r, Server, 1}`, it sends back the queuing `{f1r, self(), 2}`?

Comment: No, it does send `{f1r, Server, 1}` as well, however, when receiving, it receives `{f1r, Server, 2}` first, because it was already queued up.  The `{f1r, Server, 1}` would be waiting for a receive in the inbox. However, the code example would never receive it.